# AWS CLI updating path fails

Tags: aws-api-gateway, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to update a base path mapping from EDGE to REGIONAL with

```
aws apigateway update-domain-name --region eu-west-2 --domain-name example.com --patch-operations op=replace,path=/endpointConfiguration/types/EDGE,value=REGIONAL
```

However I get

```
An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateDomainName operation: /endpointConfiguration/types/EDGE Invalid request input
```

The docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/domainname-update/ specify that `/endpointConfiguration/types` is a valid and updateable path, however all the variations I've tried have not worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your domain name you must first add the REGIONAL type, which puts you in a safe migration state where both endpoints exist and you can flip your DNS from EDGE domain name to REGIONAL domain name (which is provided in the response after you add the REGIONAL endpoint type. You also need to patch add the regional ACM certificate separately (even if it will be the same ACM ARN).

```
aws apigateway update-domain-name --region eu-west-2 --domain-name example.com \
--patch-operations  \   
  op="add",path="/endpointConfiguration/types",value="REGIONAL" \
  op="add",path="/regionalCertificateArn",value="<ARN>"
```

After safely flipping your DNS to the regional domain name, you can remove the EDGE endpoint type.